# MySQL NDBcluster 7.3 limitation on Table Joining in a single SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-cluster

I am a novice user of Mysql database and recently my company is evaluating MySQL Cluster for its shared nothing architecture and synchronised replication.

However my colleagues informed me that the MySQL clusters will have limitation on the number of table joins you can do on one SQL statement that is **only joining not more than 5 tables**. He went to a MySQL training 1 or 2 years back, and I could not find any article or documentation on this matter.

> My web application usually query from 5-6 tables in a single SQL
>   statement. A table usually has > 200 columns and not more than 3
>   columns as combination Primary Key. The table tuples has more than 10
>   million in extreme case. The MySQL cluster will be spanning across 2
>   data centers with more than 10 data nodes. Table storage engine will be NDB for the replication capabilities.

Please let me know if more information is needed.

Any expert here is with MySQL cluster knowledge about this and able to share ? I appreciate any links or article to back the claims, thank you.

P.S.  please note the version of the mysql cluster in the title

Comment: You may be better off asking this on dba.stackexchange.com.